# Filebeat to Logstash ERR wsarecv, wsasend

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am using ELK stack version 5.1.2 and I have problem with sending logs from one worker (node) to central server. Everything I configured on localhost and it worked perfectly, but on development environment not. On localhost I used SSL, but now I turned it off. So my conf file of filebeat is:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log

paths:
    - e:\logs\*.log

document_type: xxx_log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["xxxx:5043"]

logging.level: error
logging.to_syslog: true

logging.files:
  rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

Logstash configuration:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "xxx_log" {     
        multiline {
            pattern => "^TID"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
            }
        grok {
            break_on_match => false
            match =>  [ "message", "TID: \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} \[%{JAVACLASS:java_class}\] \(%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\) - (?<log_message>(.|\r|\n)*)"]
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Ok, when I add line to log file, for example:

```
TID: [2017-01-19 13:37:18] INFO [App.java] (main) - Info test...
```

Filebeat starts  to collect data, after successfull harvest I am getting:

`ERR Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp yyyy:51992->xxxx:5043: wsasend: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Nothing in log of Logstash.

Firewall is turned off, when I open  telnet from WORK node on port 5043 message will come to central server because Logstash say in log file, that I send invalid frame type, for example I send only some POST  to test if port 5043 is open. So the port is open, but the elastic is empty. Sometimes, I do not know why, I am getting error in Filebeat log:

`wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

This line generates Logstash log:

```
11:45:31.094 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-2] ERROR org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler - Exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 83
13:31:43.139 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-4] ERROR org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler - Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Thank you for any advice.
Jaroslav

Comment: That message in Filebeat usually means it is receiving a TCP RST which Logstash does when there is congestion. Try running Logstash with no filters and only a `stdout` output (no elasticsearch) and see if the problem persists. If that works then check for problems with ES or your filters.